# Can we merge the tag ‘belt-driven-chains’ with ‘belt-drive’?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

The tag name [belt-driven-chains](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt-driven-chains) is oxymoronic: a belt is not a chain!

It makes sense to me to merge it with the simpler and more accurate [belt-drive](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt-drive).

Can this be done? How?

Comment: Belt drive as a tag makes more sense to me.

Comment: Yes, [tag:belt-drive] is obviously more correct, and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can do this. How is to post on meta (like you just did), wait for people to have a chance to comment on your proposal, then one of the moderators makes it happen.

There's also a method that high-rep users can use to create a tag synonym, but we really don't have enough users with the rep, so a meta post and moderator intervention is the way to go.

### Update: done

I looked at it, and somehow the synonym was backwards with everything being automatically rewritten as [belt-driven-chains](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt-driven-chains). I reversed the synonym and merged the tags so that everything is [belt-drive](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt-drive) now.

Comment: Thanks @freiheit. Looks like I am on the right track.